# New to Perl and Confused by hashes and bless

Tags: perl, sdk, vmware

I'm retrieving some data from an Perl library using

```
print Dumper($each_host->hardware->cpuInfo)."\n\n";
```

What I get back is .

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
             'hz' => '2199999664',
             'numCpuCores' => '20',
             'numCpuPackages' => '2',
             'numCpuThreads' => '40'
           }, 'HostCpuInfo' );
```

I have no idea how to deal with that or what bless is. My goal is just to access the raw values of the hash that was returned by the call to the Perl VMware SDK

It is coming from the VMware perl SDK.

```
my $host_view = Vim::find_entity_views(view_type=>'HostSystem',properties=>['name','config','hardware'],begin_entity=>$each_dc);
foreach my $each_host(@$host_view){
print "\n\t".$each_host->name."\n";
print Dumper($each_host->hardware->cpuInfo)."\n\n";
```

When I did Data::Printer

```
HostCpuInfo  {
Parents       DynamicData
public methods (1) : get_property_list
private methods (0)
internals: {
    hz               2199999664,
    numCpuCores      20,
    numCpuPackages   2,
    numCpuThreads    40
}
}
```

SO I changed up the code to:

```
print Dumper($each_host->hardware->cpuInfo->numCpuPackages)."\n\n";
my $array1 = $each_host->hardware->cpuInfo->get_property_list;
print 'return'.$array1."\n\n";
print Dumper($each_host->hardware->cpuInfo->get_property_list);
```

and it returns

```
$VAR1 = '2';

return4

$VAR1 = [
          'dynamicType',
          undef,
          undef,
          0
        ];
$VAR2 = [
          'dynamicProperty',
          'DynamicProperty',
          1,
          0
        ];
$VAR3 = [
          'numCpuPackages',
          undef,
          undef,
          1
        ];
$VAR4 = [
          'numCpuCores',
          undef,
          undef,
          1
        ];
$VAR5 = [
          'numCpuThreads',
          undef,
          undef,
          1
        ];
$VAR6 = [
          'hz',
          undef,
          undef,
          1
        ];
```

Thanks

Comment: It means you have an object of class `HostCpuInfo`. You should use the methods of that class to access the values, though you are able to access the referenced object as a hash.

Comment: What is the Perl library that you're using? Please show your program

Comment: updated it however again I'm unsure how to access the numCpuThreads or any of the other values in the hash

Comment: While Data::Dumper is nice to look at the underlying data structure, [Data::Printer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer) is way better for objects. It will give you a list of methods, information about values and inheritance. Install it from CPAN and use it. Or just try to call `$each_host->hardware->cupInfo->numCpuThreads`. That sounds like a reasonable guess.

Comment: ok I called 
    print Dumper($each_host->hardware->cpuInfo->numCpuPackages)."\n\n";

and got

    $VAR1 = '2';   CLOSER :)

Comment: @BostonMacOSX You shouldn't have to guess what methods an object provides: there should be documentation for each class you're using. Well-written Perl modules actually contain POD documentation directly in the source code; you can view the documentation for module Foo::Bar by running `perldoc Foo::Bar` on the command line. Hopefully the VMware SDK has decent documentation.

Comment: added Data::Printer and got see above

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot VmWare doesn't have perdocs with their classes...

Comment: According to the `Data::Printer` output, there is a method that by its name would return all properties. Try `$each_host->hardware->cpuInfo->get_property_list`.  But there has to be some documentation of the class's interface, even if there is no POD embedded in code.

Comment: @BostonMacOSX Well, they do have *some* kind of documentation. [Here's](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-60/topic/com.vmware.ICbase/PDF/vsphere-esxi-vcenter-server-60-sdk-for-perl-programming-guide.pdf) some documentation for `find_entity_views`, which says you can get a list of properties from the API reference (which I think is [here](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk41pubs/ApiReference/)).

Comment: I saw that but nowhere in their documentation do they have get_property_list as a method but there it is in the module.

Comment: If you just want to access the contents, just specify them each individually: $each_host->hardware->cpuInfo->hz etc.  If you want a hash of the data, he will have to make it yourself, since cpuInfo isn't returning a hash, its returning a HostCpuInfo object.

Comment: This helps and puzzles. The `get_property_list` returns a list. When fed into $array1 you get its lenght. That's 4 while Dumpers output gives 6 -- showing the elements to be references to arrays. However, numbers in arrays disagree with data seen directly (in two ways). I'd say that `get_property_list` merely shows which properties exist. Check: return into an array, say @properties, and iterate, dereferencing each element into an array. Test for `undef` as you print. But it seems you'll need to query directly, or find methods in docs. Report back so we can summarize this thread in a post.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you need to be reading is [*vSphere Perl SDK for vSphere 6.0*](https://developercenter.vmware.com/web/sdk/60/vsphere-perl). You need to click on the `Documentation` button under "Downloads" to get to the web page, or you can download the information for local use on your own system

If you go to that page and look in the contents section for "Writing vSphere SDK for Perl Scripts", you will see a page uselessly labelled "Working with". That leads to this page

[*Working with View Object Property Values*](https://developercenter.vmware.com/web/dp/doc/preview?id=1498#https://vdc-repo.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/2c79a0ce-6908-4d59-b927-ec7676753301/7b2fed23-1b69-4412-9e8b-f73e4fd8c73a/doc/viperl_modscripts.4.5.html)

The important information relevant to your question is this

> To access a simple property from a view, call the property’s accessor on the view object. The accessor has the same name as the property itself, as follows:
>
> ```
> $view_name->property_name
> ```

It looks like your `$each_host` is an object of type [`HostSystem`](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk25pubs/ReferenceGuide/vim.HostSystem.html), which has a property `hardware`    of type [`HostHardwareInfo`](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk25pubs/ReferenceGuide/vim.host.HardwareInfo.html), which in turn has a property `cpuInfo` of type [`HostCpuInfo`](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk25pubs/ReferenceGuide/vim.host.CpuInfo.html). The last is the object that you have dumped using `Dumper` at the start of your question

If you read the documentation for `HostCpuInfo` objects, you will see that they have four properties: `hz`, `numCpuCores`, `numCpuPackages` and `numCpuThreads`

You should be able to write code like this that accesses all four values:

```
my $cpuinfo = $each_host->hardware->cpuInfo;

for my $property ( qw/ hz numCpuCores  numCpuPackages  numCpuThreads / ) {
    printf "%s = %d\n", $property, $cpuinfo->$property;
}
```

or individually like this

```
printf "hz = %d\n", $cpuinfo->hz;
printf "numCpuCores = %d\n", $cpuinfo->numCpuCores;
printf "numCpuPackages = %d\n", $cpuinfo->numCpuPackages;
printf "numCpuThreads = %d\n", $cpuinfo->numCpuThreads;
```

Note that this is the *correct* way to access the object's properties, and uses the information in the documentation. It does not rely on any information gleaned using `Data::Dumper` or similar

I recommend that you spend some time with the documentation and familiarise yourself with the API. It looks like the facts are all there somewhere